# Changing the labels of your random-effects grouping variable changes the results in lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

The title says it all: Changing the (supposedly arbitrary) labels of your random-effects grouping variable (e.g. the names of your subjects in a repeated-measures experiment) can change the resulting output in lme4. Minimal example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(lme4)
require(digest)
df = faithful %>% mutate(subject = rep(as.character(1:8), each = 34),
                         subject2 = rep(as.character(9:16), each = 34))
summary(lmer(eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | subject), data = df))$coefficients[2,1] # = 0.07564181
summary(lmer(eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | subject2), data = df))$coefficients[2,1] # = 0.07567655
```

I think it happens because lme4 converts them to a factor, and different names produce different  factor level orderings. E.g. this produces the problem:

```
df2 = faithful %>% mutate(subject = factor(rep(as.character(1:8), each = 34)),
                          subject2 = factor(rep(as.character(9:16), each = 34)))
summary(lmer(eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | subject), data = df2))$coefficients[2,1] # = 0.07564181
summary(lmer(eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | subject2), data = df2))$coefficients[2,1] # = 0.07567655
```

But this doesn't:

```
df3 = faithful %>% mutate(subject = factor(rep(as.character(1:8), each = 34)),
                          subject2 = factor(rep(as.character(1:8), each = 34),
                                            levels = as.character(1:8),
                                            labels = as.character(9:16)))
summary(lmer(eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | subject), data = df3))$coefficients[2,1] # = 0.07564181
summary(lmer(eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | subject2), data = df3))$coefficients[2,1] # = 0.07564181
```

This seems like an issue in lme4. Different arbitrary variable labels shouldn't produce different output, right? Am I missing something? Why does lme4 do this?

(I know the difference in output is small, but I got bigger differences in other cases, enough to, e.g., change a p value from .055 to .045. Also, if this is right, I think it could cause slight reproducibility issues -- e.g. if, after finishing their analyses, an experimenter anonymizes their human subjects data (by changing the names) and then posts it in a public repository.)

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your sequence `1:8` gives the same `order` in numeric or character format, whereas the second part doesn't:

```
identical(order(1:8), order(as.character(1:8)))
# [1] TRUE
identical(order(9:16), order(as.character(9:16)))
# [1] FALSE
```

That's because numbers as characters are sorted by their first digit:

```
sort(9:16)
# [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
sort(as.character(9:16))
# [1] "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "9"
```

So if you use two different but one-digit character sequences there is seemingly no issue:

```
library(lme4)
fo1 <- eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | sub)
fo2 <- eruptions ~ waiting + (waiting | sub2)

df1 <- transform(faithful, sub=rep(as.character(1:8), each=34), 
                 sub2=rep(as.character(2:9), each=34))

summary(lmer(fo1, data=df1))$coe[2, 1]
# boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
# [1] 0.07564181
summary(lmer(fo2, data=df1))$coe[2, 1]
# boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
# [1] 0.07564181
```

**However,** the order of your grouping variables indeed do matter in `lmer()`. This can be shown by giving subject and subject2 the same levels but a different order:

```
set.seed(840947)
df2 <- transform(faithful, sub=rep(sample(1:8), each=34), sub2=rep(sample(1:8), each=34))

summary(fit2a <- lmer(fo1, data=df2))$coe[2, 1]
# boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
# [1] 0.07564179
summary(fit2b <- lmer(fo2, data=df2))$coe[2, 1]
# boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
# [1] 0.07567537
```

This yields completely different coefficients one more time. The levels and level orders may be inspected like so:

```
fit2a@flist$sub
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# [33] 4 4 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
# [65] 8 8 8 8 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# [97] 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
# [129] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
# [161] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# [193] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
# [225] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
# [257] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

fit2b@flist$sub2
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# [33] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# [65] 2 2 2 2 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
# [97] 6 6 6 6 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
# [129] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
# [161] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
# [193] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
# [225] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# [257] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

There is already a [ticket filed at github](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/449) where you should join. Perhaps try to find a similar case beforehand where there is an ordering problem, but not a singular fit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This makes sense -- this is what I was trying to gesture towards in the second part of my question, when I talked about factor level ordering (though I explained it poorly). But I think my question still stands. Why would the order of the levels in the grouping factor matter for the results? (The github ticket link is super helpful.. I will definitely join on that. Thank you!!)

Answer (score 1):

When I fit this model, I get a singular fit warning when I fit it. This is not a great sign, as the variance accounting for by just a random intercept is practically 0, and you also have a random slope. A random effect here might not be doing anything meaningful in the model.

Secondly, I question if this is the right model for this situation, what follows is unsolicited advice and I apologize if you think it is inappropriate. Second, I would have made this a comment but was unsure of how to add images.

First, I did some exploratory plots and found that both your dependent variable and fixed effect have a bimodal distribution. If we plot a scatterplot like below, we can definitely see that it might not be a linear trend.

[image]

When we then look at the model residuals, we see heteroscedasticity, which is sub-optimal. I'm not a statistician, but I've had some consultants tell me that this is one of the worst assumptions to violate in a linear model.

[image]

I think you may be seeing instability in the estimates due to the singular fit, but hopefully, someone else can come along that knows more that can clear this up.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah these are not actually the data that I initially found the problem in -- I just picked a random R dataset to produce a minimal example. And I agree that this model is obviously not a good fit for this data. But even in a poorly specified model, why would changing the arbitrary variable labels change the results? That seems like it shouldn't happen no matter what, you know? (In other words, it doesn't seem to me that the quality of the model fit should matter for this question. But I'm open to being wrong here.)